# Is the Battle of 10 kings mentioned in the Puranas or Itihasas?

Tags: vedas, puranas, history, rig-veda

Do the Puranas or Itihasas talk about the [Battle of 10 kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings) mentioned in the Rig Veda Samhita?

Since this is a historical event, it might be mentioned in the Puranas.

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't appear in itihāsa-purāṇa at all